# How to convert 1x1 cell array to 5x1 cell array of datetime string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to get *Nx1* cell array from *1x1* cell array of datetime string. Where *N* is greater than 98.

Time = {datestr(now(),'mmmm dd, yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF')};

```
Time =

  1×1 cell array

    {'January 28, 2021 12:27:15.280'}
```

I want to convert this  as

```
    Time=  
    5×1 cell array
    
        {'January 28, 2021 17:24:47.119'}
        {'January 28, 2021 17:24:47.119'}
        {'January 28, 2021 17:24:47.119'}
        {'January 28, 2021 17:24:47.119'}
        {'January 28, 2021 17:24:47.119'}
```

I am doing this using

```
Time=[Time;Time;Time;Time;Time]
```

But for variable and large value of *N*, it is very difficult.

Comment: Just for information, you might find using `datetime` arrays more flexible than `cell` arrays of strings. For more information on handling dates and times in MATLAB using `datetime`, see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `repmat`:

```
Time = {datestr(now(),'mmmm dd, yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF')};
Nrows = 100;
Ncols = 1;
Time = repmat(Time, [Nrows, Ncols]);
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks